# PDFs of old library books... Why does the text and background seem to be in separate layers?

Tags: pdf, scanning

Often, when I open a PDF, I see the background of a page come up, *before* the text elements or photos appear.

This is baffling to me, because many of these PDFs come from Google scans of old library books... not multi-layered PSDs, which is exactly how they seem to behave. 
Are the text and photo elements being literally removed from the scan -- the background being spread over the empty space -- then the text and photos being vectorized and layered back onto the background?
What is actually going on?

Comment: Feel you free to add a link of an example... Remember that you can always see a `pdf` inside and check your guess.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the OCR software being used to convert image to text automatically. This happens when I scan textbook pages wih my Xerox scanner with OCR capability. Oftentimes, the text from the resulting PDF file mat not evem be accurate or has extra spaces or are on different layers completely!

Comment: this phenomena also happens even with text so stylized it couldn't possibly be OCRed... although it could be vectorized, hence my theory...